# Does Prepaying the Last Month of Rent Lock in the Rate?

Tags: united-states, rental-property, oregon

Suppose A rents a property to B for six months. Initially, the rent is $500 per month, but A requires first and last upfront, so B pays $1000 plus deposit to move in.

During month 4, A raises the rent to $550 (following proper procedures). Does B have to pay the difference ($50) for the last month?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is rental of a residential property, the situation you describe can't happen.  Oregon Revised Statutes 90.323(3)(a) prohibits raising the rent during the first year of tenancy.

If this is a non-residential property, it will be spelled out in the rental agreement.